# Does the acceptance rate of a conference influence its reputation or rank?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Top conferences such as CVPR, ECCV, etc. typically have a low acceptance rate, i.e., ratio of accepted to submitted papers. Does this give them a high reputation or rank? For example, this year the AAAI conference has more than 8000 submitted papers but only 1000 accepted papers.

Answer (score 4):

CORE, one of the major ranking systems for computer science, takes the acceptance rate into account: [(Source)](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx3d3djb3JlZWR1fGd4OjJjNjkxOWE1NWQ4ZGY5MjU)

> Characteristics of A* Conferences include that:
>
> [...]
>
> - They have acceptance rates that are typically 20% or less, with many more "acceptable"
>     papers submitted than can be accommodated in the conference program.